# Djando DateField throws 'invalid'

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

I made an upload xlsx function where i parse each row and add each row data to a dictionary, after that i'm validating this dictionary with a form, in this form i have a DateField, if in the xlsx cell there's a correct formated date as i require in my field everything goes right, the form is valid and i can do whatever i want, but if the cell has an incorect formated date it throws this error:

```
Internal Server Error: /core/process_upload_file
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 106, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 85, in process_view
    response = panel.process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/profiling.py", line 160, in process_view
    return self.profiler.runcall(view_func, *args, **view_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/cProfile.py", line 109, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/application/core/views.py", line 567, in process_upload_file
    if form.is_valid():
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 185, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 180, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 381, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/forms.py", line 399, in _clean_fields
    value = field.clean(value)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 148, in clean
    value = self.to_python(value)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 410, in to_python
    return super().to_python(value)
  File "/Users/alex/Documents/Projects/Django/platform/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/fields.py", line 386, in to_python
    raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['invalid'], code='invalid')
KeyError: 'invalid'
```

This is the form field:

```
date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d.%m.%Y'], widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```

I want to throw a validation error that the format is incorrect, but from what i see it's like django tries to throw this validation error with invalid, but it doesn't exist. I can't do it with clean_field() since the field validates its format before it reaches my clean function.

So for example if the cell value is: 22.02.2020 it's ok, but if it's 22/02/2020 it throws the 500 error. No ideea why. I would like someone to explain and maybe give me a solution.

Comment: You're plainly only allowing `%d.%m.%Y` as an input format, so everything else is invalid.

Comment: ok, i get that, but shouldn't i get an invalid format validation error from django instead of throwing a plain 500 error?

Comment: Your `core/views.py`, line 567, `process_upload_file` function doesn't catch the `ValidationError`, so it bubbles up into a 500 error.

Comment: nah i found the problem, since i am making this project is my language, i rewritten error_messages, i did that to change required message into my language like so in the form __init__ function:
`for field in self.fields:
            self.fields[field].error_messages = {
                'required': 'Acest câmp este obligatoriu.',
            }`  but doing so it will override it and let invalid message out.

Comment: @alex: you can set an error message with `self.fields[field].error_messages['required'] = '...'`

Comment: yea i just did it like that and it works now, write it as the answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 1):

because it's validating in the model before form clean_field validation.

in the model, the date field is saved data in a format that format is specified in the settings.py file

```
USE_L10N = False

DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d-%m-%Y',
                      '%d/%m/%Y',
                      '%d.%m.%Y']
```

in form.py

```
from django.conf import settings
date = forms.DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS, widget=forms.DateInput(format='%d.%m.%Y'))
```